# Can't VPN from home client to AWS EC2 OpenVPN server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, openvpn

I've followed [this guide](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/how-to-build-your-own-vpn-if-youre-rightfully-wary-of-commercial-options) to set up my own OpenVPN server from scratch on a Ubuntu box, only that I've used AWS EC2 instead of Digital Ocean. I've got the OpenVPN server up and running as well as the client (my home desktop) duly configured. I can establish a VPN connection between the two, as I can see the `Initialization Sequence Completed` message on the client, but that's as far as it gets. After that, I can't access the Internet from the client nor ping anything at all, not even the OpenVPN server itself.

Here are a few details about my setup:

**AWS**

Ubuntu 16.04.2 running on an EC2 nano (1 core, 512MB RAM) instance on its own VPC and security group. Route table of the VPC here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIwtm.png. It has its own Internet gateway (not an NAT gateway).

`route -n` of the server

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
172.31.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The server has also an Elastic IP (static IP) allocated to it so I can SSH into it (when I'm not VPN'd, mind you) without a problem. As for the security group, my outbound traffic settings basically allow any kind of traffic to any kind of host and my inbound settings allow SSH traffic from my IP address and all UDP traffic on port 1194 from any source whatsoever (I will narrow this range down considerably but for the time being I just want to get it to work).

**Server**

iptable settings (basically none)

`iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:2e:e3:58:d0:26  
          inet addr:172.31.1.187  Bcast:172.31.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e:e3ff:fe58:d026/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:18447 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15656 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2083132 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:2408726 (2.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:96332 (96.3 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp

dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key

dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh2048.pem

topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Use Google's DNS servers to resolve external addresses
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120

cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

**OpenVPN Version**

```
OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
```

**OpenVPN syslog snippet on startup and when the client connects**

```
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2525]: OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2525]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: PID file /run/openvpn/server.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to server.
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.2 size=252, ipv6=0
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: ifconfig_pool_read(), in='client-with-pass,10.8.0.4', TODO: IPv6
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: succeeded -> ifconfig_pool_set()
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: ifconfig_pool_read(), in='client-pass,10.8.0.8', TODO: IPv6
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: succeeded -> ifconfig_pool_set()
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-with-pass,10.8.0.4
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass,10.8.0.8
Jun  4 21:12:53 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]<ip>:31969, sid=f42796e8 a043209b
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=GB, ST=CA, L=Cambridge, O=Anonymous, OU=Anonymous, CN=Anonymous CA, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=anon@anon.com
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=GB, ST=CA, L=Cambridge, O=Anonymous, OU=Anonymous, CN=client-pass, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=anon@anon.com
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: <ip>:31969 [client-pass] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]<ip>:31969
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass/<ip>:31969 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.8, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass/<ip>:31969 MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.8 -> client-pass/<ip>:31969
Jun  4 21:13:06 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass/<ip>:31969 MULTI: primary virtual IP for client-pass/<ip>:31969: 10.8.0.8
Jun  4 21:13:07 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass/<ip>:31969 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Jun  4 21:13:07 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass/<ip>:31969 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
Jun  4 21:13:07 ip-172-31-1-187 ovpn-server[2528]: client-pass/<ip>:31969 SENT CONTROL [client-pass]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.8 255.255.255.0' (status=1)
```

**Client**

client.ovpn

```
ca ca.crt
cert client-pass.crt
key client-pass.key

remote <server_public_ip> 1194
comp-lzo
client
dev tun
redirect-gateway def1

remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1

proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

topology subnet
pull

persist-key
persist-tun

verb 3
mute 20
```

**OpenVPN Version**

```
OpenVPN 2.4.2 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 11 2017
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.08
```

**Client's routing table when connected to the VPN server**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
<vpn_server_public_ip>   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
```

As I said, judging by the stdout logs printed on both ends, VPN connection seems to be established OK but then the client has no network/Internet access at all.

I've spent a good amount of time troubleshooting this, looking into possible AWS security group issues, config file issues (e.g. mismatched settings between the client and server conf files), firewall issues on both ends, I have even run tcpdump on the server and could see incoming packets from the client although I'm not an expert at analysing network packet dumps so I couldn't really draw any solid conclusions by looking at it... Could anyone offer some help with this? I'd appreciate it immensely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVPN config seems to be fine, as well as route tables.

It would be great to have the log for the client as well (just in case), and the outputs for the tests you are doing (traceroute? ping? nc?) between the client and the server.

But anyway, in my opinion the problem is that you are missing some config at the server OS.

Have a look at: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting (Using routing)

And you will notice that you should:

- Enable IP Forwarding
- Allow traffic forwarding with IPTables. From the VPN to "the world", for established connections, and deny everything else (or define deny as default rule).
- Enable masquerading from the VPN to "the world"

That is, if you do not want to use the VPN to access other EC2 at the same VPC (in that case you will need to add some more rules to forward between VPN and the VPC).

Comment: It was those two last steps you outlined what I was missing. I ran the iptables commands in the wiki article of your post and it worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!